# "Error: not found: make" installing Meteorite on OS X

Tags: meteorite

I'm trying to install meteorite on OS X 10.8.4. When I run this

> sudo -H npm install -g meteorite

I see

> ws@0.4.27 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Looking at the builderror.log I see

> gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.15/node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
>   gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.15/node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
>   gyp ERR! build error 
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
>   gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
>   gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
>   gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
>   gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws
>   gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
>   gyp ERR! not ok

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have make installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the native build tools installed?  If not, install them.  This can be done using Xcode very easily.  In the Xcode "Downloads" preference window.

Here's what appears to be your exact issue on another package: https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/142

Comment: As soon as I posted the question I realized that was the issue. However, after installing the command line tools I'm now getting thishttps://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/mrt -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js

Comment: If 'npm cache clean' doesn't help, I'd recommend posting a new question!

Comment: Apparently, that output doesn't actually indicate an error and is normal. I thought it wasn't working because "mrt" wasn't being recognized but that was because /usr/local/share/npm/bin was not on the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "install the command line tools" is the answer, in Xcode 5.1.1, `xcode-select --install` was not yet available.  Here's how you do it in Xcode 5.1.1 (also works with older versions)

- Applications
- Xcode (Launch the IDE from your Apps)
- Xcode Preferences menu (Top left, next to Apple logo)
- Downloads tab
- Components: Command Line Tools
- Install (Download Arrow)